# React-bootstrap onSelect method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

im using react-bootstrap `DropdownButton`,   what i want to do is,

when i click on one of the `MenuItem`s ,

the `onSelect` will run a function named `fltrPick()` 
that is setting a new state `setState({fltr:"some string"})`

i bind `fltrPick()` like this `let pickHeaderSet = fltrPick.bind(this)`

and when i load the page the buttons dosent even appears

here is my code

```
     fltrFunc:function(name){
       function fltrPick(pick){
          this.setState({fltrName:pick})
        }
        let pickHeaderSet = fltrPick.bind(this)
        switch(name){
           case "processors":
             return (
              <DropdownButton id="dropdownBtn" bsSize="xsmall"  title={name} >
               <MenuItem eventKey="1" onSelect={pickHeaderSet("pentium")} >pentium </MenuItem>  
              //the one above make the problam why ? 
               <MenuItem eventKey="2">i3</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem eventKey="3">i7</MenuItem> 
              </DropdownButton>
                    )
             braek;
                   }
      },
```

Comment: Why you are binding  pickHeaderSet to fltrPick?

Comment: i didnt relize the mistake

Comment: but y the vote down :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor you should bind it this way

```
this.fltrPick = this.fltrPick.bind(this);
```

Reference : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are calling that function on the render?

Your code should look something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fltrFunc = this.fltrFunc.bind(this);
  }

        fltrFunc(name) {
        this.setState({ filterName: name });
        switch (name) {
          case 'processors': {
            return (
              <DropdownButton id="dropdownBtn" bsSize="xsmall"  title={name} >
                <MenuItem eventKey="1" onSelect={() => this.pickHeaderSet("pentium")}>pentium</MenuItem>  
                <MenuItem eventKey="2">i3</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey="3">i7</MenuItem> 
              </DropdownButton>
            );
          }
          default:
        }
      }

        render() {
            return ({this.fltrFunc()});
       }
```